# Reading txtfiles from servers stops "halfway through"

Tags: java

I hope to get an answer to this, this is really troubling me... I am using a scanner to read from a txtfile on a server. And this far all I want to do is to do a System.out.println with the contents of the textfile with each row on the server being a new row on my screen.

I have a arrayList with servers (the number of servers differ from time to time. Then I use the a for loop that goes through the arrayList and for each server I want to read the textfile in the url in the arraylist. My problem is that it only reads and prints about half of the first textfile, then it just seems to stop or freeze... no error messages or anything.

The code i am using to get the server adress is this:

```
for(int x=0;x protected void processLine(String aLine){ '
// System.out.println("processLine körs"); 
//use a second Scanner to parse the content of each line Scanner scanner = 
new Scanner(aLine); scanner.useDelimiter (System.getProperty("line.separator"));

if ( scanner.hasNext() ){ //System.out.println("scanner.hasNext()");

// String[] str = scanner.next().split(":"); String str = scanner.next(); log(str); } }

private static void log(String tmp){

//if (tmp.length>1){ // if (tmp[0].equals("url0")){ // pilotServer = new 
PilotServer(tmp[1]); // addServer(pilotServer); // } // } 
System.out.println("UsersOnline :"+tmp); }
```

I hope this makes sense:)

Comment: Your code is unreadable and there is obvously an error in it. Could you fix it, first?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the textfile encoding. hasNext() method of the Scanner class sometimes returns false, when it reaches some characters of different encodings and your loop would just stop. You can easily check this with checking the line in the textfile, at which your application stops processing.

Answer (score 0):

If the code just freezes looks like the server is not sending you data, so the scanner just sits there waiting for it.

You could try to download the file to a tmp location and then read it.